# Workflow Rule on Case Comment, Fire Action on Case

Tags: workflow, case, case-object

I would like to fire a workflow whenever a case comment is created that emails both the case owner and a custom lookup field on the Case Object. I've created one for new Cases fine but when I fire on Case Comments I'm unable to access fields on the Case object as email recipients.

Is there any way to do this with workflows or should I resort to using a trigger on CaseComment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you cannot directly do this via workflow.

Rather than resort to a trigger though, can I suggest the following approach.

Use a **Workflow** rule on **Case Comment** to enact a **field update** on the parent **Case**, which (ensuring you re-evaluate workflow afterwards) can then fire a **Workflow rule** on the **Case** (due to the update) that **sends an e-mail** out to the Case Owner and your custom field?!

[image: diagram]

Sounds complicated, but it's not, I promise.

If that "solution" is enough for you to follow through, then perfect, if not you can read/follow [this blog post which I wrote to set a custom template](http://srlawr.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/modifying-new-email-on-case-template-in.html), which uses this exact Workflow pair to send the Case owner an e-mail on Case Comment creation - just ignore the custom template bit and follow the additional field work and workflows to trigger the e-mail.

You need the new field and updates etc. on the Case so you only fire the "updated" workflow when it is a new Case Comment causing the update, and not just a user editing a case.