# SOAP API - Post Call Log into chatter

Tags: soap-api, chatter, casefeed

Is there any way to publish CallLog object into chatter feed (for case object) ?

I read about [CaseFeed object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casefeed.htm) but it's read-only.

I'm using developer version with cloud service.

Comment: Do you mean you what to post CallLog detail to case feed?

Comment: Yes, i want to post calllog detail to case feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConnectApi to post feed to chatter.

```
ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), '0F9d0000000TreH', ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'On vacation this week.');
```

for more details on ConnectApi please refer: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activating_computer.htm&type=0&language=en_US

The other piece that you will need is trigger to initiate the posting for that you can refer this answer:

[Workflow Rule on Case Comment, Fire Action on Case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34747/workflow-rule-on-case-comment-fire-action-on-case)